# Need to Release UIWebView Delegate?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView named wView. I want to use `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in my class, so I am setting the class as the delegate for wView by using this line:

```
wView.delegate = self;
```

Everything loads properly, but when I close the UIWebView, the App crashes. If I comment out the `wView.delegate = self`, it works and does not crash, but then I can't use `webViewDidFinishLoad:` - any ideas? Do I need to release something?

Comment: Add the exact error you get to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [UIWebView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> Important: Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to nil. This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to set the delegate to nil (wView.delegate = nil). This will prevent webview from trying to access and call methods on a dealloc'd view controller, which would result in a crash.